# Changing a Firebird Alias' parameters on run-time

Tags: delphi, alias, firebird, interbase

In my application I have a set of three buttons. When I click on each one it connects to a different piece of software with a separate database each time. However the connection works easily through one Alias. However when I click the button it changed the alias' parameters to reflect the new databases directory.

This worked correctly and exactly as I wanted when I was running Interbase. I have now converted to using Firebird, but haven't changed any of the programs functionality. It should by rights all work the same. The only difference is, I am now using Firebird and the Alias is installed via the Firebird ODBC Driver.

Does anyone know of any quick fixes without having to hardcode the directories in each separate program?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand, are we talking about DB alias or some product called Alias (since I don't understand what *the Alias is installed via the Firebird ODBC Driver* means) ? You are connected to a FB database through an alias and someone changes settings of that alias. Then you reconnect and what happens ? Or did I get that completely wrong ?

Comment: Sorry, yes I am on about a DB alias. My fault for badly wording, I'm pretty new to the jargon. So I am connecting to a FB database through an alias. And the programs I run change the Alias' details (specifically the database path) so that it can connect to various databases. This worked before i swapped from Interbase to Firebird.

Comment: Which Firebird architecture do you have installed? SuperServer, Classic or SuperClassic? A workaround might be to install Classic.

Answer (score 0):

Firebird stores its aliases in `aliases.conf` (versions prior to 3.x) or `databases.conf` (3.x). Firebird seems to re-read the file when it gets modified so all a client has to do is re-establish every connection. I have no idea what

> Alias is installed via the Firebird ODBC Driver

means though. How

> the programs I run change the Alias' details (specifically the database path) so that it can connect to various databases

is implemented? I believe the problem is here.

Comment: When I say the Alias is installed via the Firebird ODBC Driver, I mean that I have downloaded the Firebird ODBC Driver and then used windows built in ODBC Administrator to set up the alias, rather than using something like BDE. Whilst the implementation could be the problem, it wasn't before when I was using Interbase, it worked perfectly fine at changing the Alias' details.

Comment: @gn12345 ODBC driver sets up his own alias which is completely different from Firebird alias. I guess you should clarify this in the question text and add ODBC tag because it is Firebird alias that people think of by default.

Comment: I didn't realise they were different, I believed them to be linked like most aliases used in ODBC. Thanks for the information and sorry for the inconvenience.